# Issue with EDT violation when launching Component Inspector, probably related to use of CSS

Tags: codenameone

since I started using the css (activated "CSS Theme Support" in the CN1 settings), whenever I launch the Component Inspector in the simulator, I get a load of stack trace errors (example below) before the Inspector shows. It seems more or less one stackTrace for each component shown on the screen, although I've not checked. In the end the inspector shows up and works correctly, but it often takes 30-60s to show all the stack traces first...

It doesn't happen for a small test example, so it seems it's specific to my code, but since I don't see anything related to my code in the stack trace I'm a bit at a loss about what causes it. Any suggestions or paths for investigation?

Thanks

```
EDT violation detected!
com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaSEPort$EDTViolation: EDT Violation Stack!
at com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaSEPort.checkEDT(JavaSEPort.java:918)
at com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaSEPort.createFont(JavaSEPort.java:6212)
at com.codename1.ui.Font.<init>(Font.java:99)
at com.codename1.ui.Font.createSystemFont(Font.java:345)
at com.codename1.ui.util.Resources.loadTheme(Resources.java:1351)
at com.codename1.ui.util.Resources.openFileImpl(Resources.java:305)
at com.codename1.ui.util.Resources.openFile(Resources.java:271)
at com.codename1.ui.util.Resources.<init>(Resources.java:191)
at com.codename1.ui.util.Resources.open(Resources.java:742)
at com.codename1.ui.util.Resources.open(Resources.java:679)
at com.codename1.impl.javase.ComponentTreeInspector.<init>(ComponentTreeInspector.java:81)
at com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaSEPort$20.actionPerformed(JavaSEPort.java:2937)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(AbstractButton.java:376)
at com.apple.laf.ScreenMenuItem.actionPerformed(ScreenMenuItem.java:125)
at java.awt.MenuItem.processActionEvent(MenuItem.java:669)
at java.awt.MenuItem.processEvent(MenuItem.java:628)
at java.awt.MenuComponent.dispatchEventImpl(MenuComponent.java:357)
at java.awt.MenuComponent.dispatchEvent(MenuComponent.java:345)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:761)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an EDT violation in our code. It's not a big one and is actually permissible so this code is legal. However, the EDT violation detection code can't tell the difference between our code and yours. It can't tell whether a specific violation is "OK". So it prints this warning with a stack trace as a false positive.

Comment: Thanks, that's good to know. Is there any way to prevent it (since it makes it quite slow to launch the Component Inspector)?

Comment: Just disabled the EDT logging when it isn't in use

Comment: I first misunderstood your comment to mean that you would disable the EDT logging when not in use. Just to clarify for others with the same issue: you simply need to set the simulator option "Debug EDT" to Light (which will still show violations, but not stack trace, so less time spend waiting). Setting it "None" will hide violations completely so probably best to avoid.